# How to get names of objects merged from different branch in Git

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I am trying to get the names on objects merged in the last commit and then trying to zip all those files. i already have the archive command which will take those files and zip them. Below command will zip all the files in the branch.

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD
```

but if i can somehow get the command to get the list of objects merged from different branch, i can combine these two commands and zip only those objects as shown below.

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(COMMAND TO GET NAME from last merge)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me quite what this means.  Let's try an example.

```
$ git checkout main
[checkout message]
$ git merge sidebranch
[merge messages]
```

Suppose that in the merge base commit between the tip of `main` and the tip of `sidebranch`, we had files `A`, `B`, and `C`.

By the tip of `main`, we had files `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.  `A` is not changed since the merge base, `B` is changed, `C` is not changed, and `D` is new.

In `sidebranch`, we modified `B` since the merge base, *removed* `C`, and added `E`.

The result of the merge is therefore:

- file `A` is unchanged since the base: it's still unchanged;
- both changes to file `B` are mushed together (and maybe some conflicts resolved);
- file `C` is removed entirely;
- file `D` remains as it was in the previous tip of `main`; and
- file `E` is added in the new merge commit in `main`, in the same form it has in the tip of `sidebranch`.

What would you like in your zip archive?  Only file `B` had actual merging done.  File `E` is new, but there was no merging.  File `C` is *gone:* how will you represent this in your archive?

**To get a list of what changed between the previous branch tip of `main` and what is in the current branch tip of `main`**, you can do:

```
git diff --name-status <previous-hash> main
```

which will show `B` modified, `C` deleted, and `E` added.  You can spell the previous hash using `main^` or `main~1`, but this makes a rather bold assumption.

Probably the best way to find the previous hash that was saved on some other machine to which you are transporting this archive is to save the hash at the time you make the setup on the other machine.  That is, if the overall process is:

- make an initial archive from HEAD;
- copy the archive to machine *M;*
- later, try to update *M* somehow, without using a whole new archive

we would like to save, at the time we make the initial archive, the hash ID to which `HEAD` translates.  There are many ways to do that, such as saving the output of `git rev-parse HEAD` in a file, or creating a [tag](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html).

#### Conclusion

If all this is correct, then you may wish to:

1. make a tag each time you make an archive or archive-update;
2. use `git diff --name-status` or similar to compare two tags;
3. figure out some way to represent this change as a set of changes that can be applied: a zip archive will not do the trick as it will not handle removals.

Comment: Thanks Torek for the reply.                                  We have developers commit to their own branch and then merge all the changes to Dev branch. from there Team lead merge the Dev branch to Test branch and again from Test branch to Master Branch.What we are trying to achieve is as per your example is Lets say file A has been changed in branch Dev and file E has been added to Branch DEV and both merged to branch Test and again to Master, we would like the name displayed of both the files from the command so the archive command can zip them. Also run this command from Master branch only.

Comment: See the line written in bold-face: `git diff --name-status` gets you the set of files added, deleted, and modified (and maybe renamed, depending on whether you enable rename detection). But it's up to you to figure out how to turn that information into something you can use.